# Flutter error occurs : The position being added ($position) has a smaller timestamp ($time) than its predecessor: $previousPoint

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a poblem with scrolling page that built with NestedScrollView.There is a certain probability of reporting errors at the beginning of scrolling.Here see the error:

```
I/flutter ( 6574): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY GESTURE LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 6574): The following assertion was thrown while routing a pointer event:
I/flutter ( 6574): The position being added (Offset(71.3, 253.9)) has a smaller timestamp (106:11:02.860000)than its
I/flutter ( 6574): predecessor: _PointAtTime(Offset(71.0, 252.9) at 106:11:02.867000).
I/flutter ( 6574): 
I/flutter ( 6574): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter ( 6574): #0      IOSScrollViewFlingVelocityTracker.addPosition.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/gestures/velocity_tracker.dart:307:7)
I/flutter ( 6574): #1      IOSScrollViewFlingVelocityTracker.addPosition (package:flutter/src/gestures/velocity_tracker.dart:311:6)
I/flutter ( 6574): #2      DragGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/monodrag.dart:277:15)
I/flutter ( 6574): #3      PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:77:12)
I/flutter ( 6574): #4      PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:122:9)
I/flutter ( 6574): #5      _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:377:8)
I/flutter ( 6574): #6      PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:120:18)
I/flutter ( 6574): #7      PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:106:7)
I/flutter ( 6574): #8      GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:358:19)
I/flutter ( 6574): #9      GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:338:22)
I/flutter ( 6574): #10     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:267:11)
I/flutter ( 6574): #11     GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:295:7)
I/flutter ( 6574): #12     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:240:7)
I/flutter ( 6574): #13     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:213:7)
I/flutter ( 6574): #17     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:265:10)
I/flutter ( 6574): #18     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:174:5)
I/flutter ( 6574): (elided 3 frames from dart:async)
I/flutter ( 6574): 
I/flutter ( 6574): router: Instance of 'PointerRouter'
I/flutter ( 6574): route: Closure: (PointerEvent) => void from Function 'handleEvent':.
I/flutter ( 6574): event: PointerMoveEvent#0e017(position: Offset(71.3, 372.3))
I/flutter ( 6574): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Flutter environment info:

[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.5, on macOS 11.1 20C69 darwin-x64, locale
zh-Hans-CN)
• Flutter version 1.22.5 at /Users/fox/Documents/flutter
• Framework revision 7891006299 (3 months ago), 2020-12-10 11:54:40 -0800
• Engine revision ae90085a84
• Dart version 2.10.4
• Pub download mirror https://pub.flutter-io.cn
• Flutter download mirror https://storage.flutter-io.cn

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
• Android SDK at /Users/fox/Library/Android/sdk
• Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
• Java binary at: /Applications/Android
Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.3)
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• Xcode 12.3, Build version 12C33
• CocoaPods version 1.10.1

[!] Android Studio (version 4.1)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
• YAL AL10 (mobile)          • 6QDDU19627031486                     •
android-arm64 • Android 10 (API 29)
• iPhone 12 Pro Max (mobile) • BFF76ECD-93DE-4C0F-A171-BC1B705FF802 • ios
• com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14-3 (simulator)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.

Comment: Facing the same issue, did you find any solution?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to resolve this issue with deleting the following line in my main.dart file:

```
GestureBinding.instance!.resamplingEnabled = true;
```